# Awk for a string containing the special character "."

Tags: unix, awk

This seems like an easy question, but I have tried a number of approaches I've found in other questions but have had no luck.

I am simply trying to use awk to look for the string (ExAC_ALL=.) within the 8th column of a txt file, however the speacial character "." seems to be causing issues.

The code I am trying to use is

```
> awk ' ($8 ~ "ExAC_ALL=.") {print $0}' input.txt > output.txt
```

I have also tried:

```
> EXAC="ExAC_ALL=." 
> awk -v NAME="$EXAC" '$8 ~ NAME { print $0 }' input.txt > output.txt
```

I have also tried escaping the "." symbol multiple ways.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a single-backslash to escape the period.

For example, consider this input file:

```
$ cat file
ExAC_ALL=1
ExAC_ALL=.
ExAC_ALL=*
```

To get the lines you want:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /ExAC_ALL=\./' file
ExAC_ALL=.
```

#### Discussion

With out the backslash, the period is a wildcard character: it matches any character.  Thus:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /ExAC_ALL=./' file
ExAC_ALL=1
ExAC_ALL=.
ExAC_ALL=*
```

With the backslash, it will only match a period.

#### Alternative

Alternatively, one could put the period in square brackets:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /ExAC_ALL=[.]/' file
ExAC_ALL=.
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try like below

```
$ EXAC="ExAC_ALL=[.]" 
$ awk -v NAME="$EXAC" '$8 ~ NAME { print $0 }'  input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

for fixed string matching, avoid regex and use `index` - it returns position of match and `0` if no match is found

```
awk 'index($8, "ExAC_ALL=.")' ip.txt
```

for passing string from shell, use environment variable instead of `-v` option, this will prevent backslash interpretations

```
name="ExAC_ALL=." awk 'index($8, ENVIRON["name"])' ip.txt
```

for ex:

```
$ echo 'a\b' | awk -v s='\b' 'index($1, s)'
$ echo 'a\b' | s='\b' awk 'index($1, ENVIRON["s"])'
a\b
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer : it is much more versatile and does "the right thing" in most cases and is more generic than the accepted answer. It makes the code easier to read than having '\' prepended (and also makes it easier if the thing to be looked for is *not known in advance* and is in a variable, and may contain a special (in the regex sense) character such as : $, ^, ., etc. )